# No "current-menu-ancestor" class added when browsing an archive page

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I have a menu set up like this:

```
Page 1
Page 2
    Page 2.1
    CPT Archive
    Page 2.2
Page 3
etc...
```

And when I navigate to the Archive, the Page 2 menu item does not have the "current-menu-ancestor" or "current-menu-item" classes.

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding how WordPress menu classes should work?

Comment: I believe that's correct. There's no relation liking the Archive page and Page 2. The nesting done in appearances -> menu, does not create a relation.

Comment: Ah, I expected the two classes to be added depending on the structure of the menu, not the page hierarchy. Too bad! Guess I'll just use a page and a shortcode instead. Thanks.

Comment: You can also try using body classes. So your menu highlight would change according to the body class on the document.

Comment: You can also use the [`nav_menu_css_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class) filter to modify classes for specific menu items.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is being fixed in the next version of Wordpress. As a ticket with a patch is now labeled 4.8, check https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39800.

Comment: Just for the records, it was not patched in 4.8. The ticket milestone has been changed for future release